# Executing script containing variables

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Inside an script we are executing another script in the same directory which contain some variables definition:

**SCRIPT1:**

```
cd $configDir
script=PLS00170.sh
./config_fecha$script.sh

if [ ! -f /f_PL_50007622_Hist_Rel_Sico_Vta_Cp.$F1S4_FEOPERACA1 ]
```

**config_fechaPLS00170.sh.sh:**

```
#! /bin/ksh
#------------------------------------
#FEOPERAC
#------------------------------------
F1S4_FEOPERACA1=20150401
....
```

The Script 1 is not able to resolve the script `$F1S4_FEOPERACA1`:

Sysout:

```
...
+ ./config_fechaPLS00170.sh.sh
+ [ ! -f /f_PL_50007622_Hist_Rel_Sico_Vta_Cp. ]
...
```

Any idea?

Comment: Ugh. Why are you embedding data in the file name of the script, rather than just passing an argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're executing the second script in its own process, so any variables defined there will be lost when it exits.

You could instead "source" the second script into the first one. This will run it as if the text was literally there. You can do that with

```
. ./config_fechaPLS00170.sh.sh    # note the first dot, then a space
```

or

```
source ./config_fechaPLS00170.sh.sh
```